# JavaFX TableView seperate bean adapter for each row. How?

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, tableview, javabeans

Having problems to bind bean adapter objects to TableView, which creates combobox with that adapter property.

```
lanSpecie.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<HAUL,Specie>, TableCell<HAUL,Specie>>() {
    @Override
    public TableCell<HAUL, Specie> call(TableColumn<HAUL, Specie> param) {
        TableCell<HAUL, Specie> cell = new TableCell<>();
        ComboBox<Specie> comboBox = new ComboBox<>(FXCollections.observableList(specieService.findAllAdded()));
            try {
                comboBox.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(new JavaBeanObjectPropertyBuilder<Object>().bean(haulBean).name("specie").build());
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            cell.graphicProperty().bind(Bindings.when(cell.emptyProperty()).then((Node) null).otherwise(comboBox));
            return cell;
        }
    });
```

My table with 3 rows added:

[image: Haul table]

Whenever I change one element, it automatically changes all 3.

Looking for solution or guide in the right direction, so that the table looks for each row element as a new HAUL object thus creating new adapter instance for each row.

Comment: What is `haulBean` in that code? It looks like you are binding the value of all the combo boxes to a single property. Can't you just use a standard [`ComboBoxTableCell`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/ComboBoxTableCell.html) here?

Comment: haulBean is my entity object (POJO in this case).
Can you bind javabean adapter field to ComboBoxTableCell?

Comment: But which entity object? You have one for each row. That doesn't really make sense. You should use the cell *value* factory to map to the Java Bean Adapter, and then use the cell factory to specify the table cell. I don't see any reason that wouldn't work with a `ComboBoxTableCell`.

Comment: Like this? [link](https://gist.github.com/Kefirchiks/d58a504154162cf134d0a9f79bdf10c5)

Comment: Sort of, but again it looks like you are using the same value for every row: `haulBean` is still value for just one fixed row. You surely want `new JavaBeanObjectPropertyBuilder<Object>().bean(param.getValue())...`

Comment: I think you just saved my whole day with that `param.getValue())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The individual values for a cell are passed into the cell's `updateItem(...)` method when the cell needs to display a new value (e.g. when the cell is initialized, if the property changes, if the cell is reused for a new value, etc). You can control the *value* that is passed into the cell using the `cellValueFactory`:

```
lanSpecie.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
    new JavaBeanObjectPropertyBuilder<Specie>()
        .bean(cellData.getValue())
        .name("specie")
        .build());
```

Having done that, you can get the functionality you need for the cell using the standard `ComboBoxTableCell`:

```
lanSpecie.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(
    FXCollections.observableList(specieService.findAllAdded()));
```

The `ComboBoxTableCell` is doing something like you would get with the following:

```
lanSpecie.setCellFactory(column -> new TableCell<HAUL, Specie>() {
    private final ComboBox<Specie> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();

    {
        comboBox.setItems(FXCollections.observableList(specieService.findAllAdded()));
        comboBox.setOnAction(e -> commitEdit(comboBox.getValue()));
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Specie specie, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(specie, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            comboBox.setValue(specie);
            setGraphic(comboBox);
        }
    }
});

lanSpecie.setOnEditCommit(event -> {
    HAUL haul = event.getRowValue();
    haul.setSpecie(event.getNewValue());
});
```

Comment: Many thanks!
Is there a way, that I can use `ComboBox` instead of `ComboBoxTableCell` and bind its value property to my JavabeanObjectProperty?

Comment: @Kefirchiks Well, the combo box table cell does exactly that for you, but you could just (re)implement it yourself if you really wanted to. I don't think you can use a binding, per se, because the cell value factory necessarily creates a new property instance each time it's called, so you would need listeners instead.

Comment: @Kefirchiks See update for example of implementing the cell yourself. This cell implementation is a bit basic, and doesn't move in and out of editing state in the way the standard cell does, but it should work (not tested).

Comment: Used it like [this](https://gist.github.com/Kefirchiks/61f7ccbc254e85e45232d72fa8698287) but I have a problem. It loads multiple times. Whenever I change value, my change listener shows [this](http://prnt.sc/ez2we6) in console and value has been changed multiple times.